# How to print when the expression equals the result

Tags: python, generator

```
vals = [1, 2, 3, 4]
operators = ['+', '*', '-', '/']
result=10

def expressions(values):

    if len(values) == 1:
        yield values


    for i in range(len(values)):

        forward = values[:]
        val = forward.pop(i)


        for op in operators:
            for rest in expressions(forward):
                yield [val, op] + rest
```

[image: 1]

I am stuck on this, is there any way I could print the expression which equals the result number which is being inputted by the user and not every single permutation possible.

EDIT: If u could see i have a variable called result, now with all the permuted expression, i want to print the expression which equals the result

Comment: can you please give me more information? this question is not clear.

Comment: Please include any code and data in your post itself, not as images.

Comment: editted , pasted the code

Answer (score 1):

If you convert integers to strings then you can concatenate every permutation to string and you could use with `eval()` to calculatet it - ie `if eval("1+2+3+4") == 10:`

```
vals = [1, 2, 3, 4]
operators = ['+', '*', '-', '/']
result = 10

def expressions(values):

    if len(values) == 1:
        yield values

    for i in range(len(values)):

        forward = values[:]
        val = forward.pop(i)


        for op in operators:
            for rest in expressions(forward):
                yield [val, op] + rest


for x in expressions(vals):
    x = ' '.join(map(str, x))
    if eval(x) == result:
        print(x, '=', eval(x))
```

---

**EDIT:** for @lbragile version with `return`

```
vals = [1, 2, 3, 4]
operators = ['+', '*', '-', '/']
result = 10

def expressions(values):

    if len(values) == 1:
        return [values]  # has to return list of lists

    results = [] # create list for all lists

    for i in range(len(values)):

        forward = values[:]
        val = forward.pop(i)

        for op in operators:
            for rest in expressions(forward):
                results.append([val, op] + rest)

    return results # return all lists at once


for x in expressions(vals):
    x = ' '.join(map(str, x))
    if eval(x) == result:
        print(x, '=', eval(x))
```

Comment: @furas may I ask why you used `yield` rather than `return`?

Comment: @lbragile I use code from question and OP used `yield`. I didn't even check what is in code.

Comment: @furas I see. I think it is because of the `pop( )` which reduces the list size each recursive call and yield simply "generates" the output. I am not sure why using `return` gives: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
    for x in expressions(vals):
  File "main.py", line 13, in expressions
    for rest in expressions(forward):
  File "main.py", line 13, in expressions
    for rest in expressions(forward):
  File "main.py", line 14, in expressions
    return [val, op] + rest
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list`

Comment: @lbragile for `return` you would have to create list with all results and then `return` this list of lists. Because it returns list of lists so it would need also `[]` in `return [values]` to create list of lists - list with one list `values`

Comment: @lbragile I added to answer version with `return`

Answer (score 1):

To add to @furas answer, I think the following has better coding syntax:

```
def expressions(vals):
  global operators

  if len(vals) == 1:
    yield vals

  else:
    for i in range(len(vals)):
      forward = vals[:]
      val = forward.pop(i)

      for op in operators:
        for rest in expressions(forward):
          yield [val, op] + rest

vals = [1, 2, 3, 4]
operators = ['+', '*', '-', '/']
result = 10

for x in expressions(vals):
  x = ' '.join(map(str, x))
  if eval(x) == result:
    print("{} = {}".format(x, int(eval(x))))
```

## Output:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
1 + 2 + 4 + 3 = 10
1 + 3 + 2 + 4 = 10
1 + 3 + 4 + 2 = 10
1 + 4 + 2 + 3 = 10
1 + 4 + 3 + 2 = 10
1 * 2 * 3 + 4 = 10
1 * 3 * 2 + 4 = 10
1 * 3 * 4 - 2 = 10
1 * 4 + 2 * 3 = 10
1 * 4 + 3 * 2 = 10
1 * 4 * 3 - 2 = 10
2 + 1 + 3 + 4 = 10
2 + 1 + 4 + 3 = 10
2 + 3 + 1 + 4 = 10
2 + 3 + 4 + 1 = 10
2 + 4 + 1 + 3 = 10
2 + 4 + 3 + 1 = 10
2 * 1 * 3 + 4 = 10
2 * 3 + 1 * 4 = 10
2 * 3 + 4 * 1 = 10
2 * 3 + 4 / 1 = 10
2 * 3 * 1 + 4 = 10
2 * 3 / 1 + 4 = 10
2 * 4 + 3 - 1 = 10
2 * 4 - 1 + 3 = 10
2 / 1 * 3 + 4 = 10
3 + 1 + 2 + 4 = 10
3 + 1 + 4 + 2 = 10
3 + 2 + 1 + 4 = 10
3 + 2 + 4 + 1 = 10
3 + 2 * 4 - 1 = 10
3 + 4 + 1 + 2 = 10
3 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 10
3 + 4 * 2 - 1 = 10
3 * 1 * 2 + 4 = 10
3 * 1 * 4 - 2 = 10
3 * 2 + 1 * 4 = 10
3 * 2 + 4 * 1 = 10
3 * 2 + 4 / 1 = 10
3 * 2 * 1 + 4 = 10
3 * 2 / 1 + 4 = 10
3 * 4 * 1 - 2 = 10
3 * 4 - 1 * 2 = 10
3 * 4 - 2 * 1 = 10
3 * 4 - 2 / 1 = 10
3 * 4 / 1 - 2 = 10
3 - 1 + 2 * 4 = 10
3 - 1 + 4 * 2 = 10
3 / 1 * 2 + 4 = 10
3 / 1 * 4 - 2 = 10
4 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 10
4 + 1 + 3 + 2 = 10
4 + 1 * 2 * 3 = 10
4 + 1 * 3 * 2 = 10
4 + 2 + 1 + 3 = 10
4 + 2 + 3 + 1 = 10
4 + 2 * 1 * 3 = 10
4 + 2 * 3 * 1 = 10
4 + 2 * 3 / 1 = 10
4 + 2 / 1 * 3 = 10
4 + 3 + 1 + 2 = 10
4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 10
4 + 3 * 1 * 2 = 10
4 + 3 * 2 * 1 = 10
4 + 3 * 2 / 1 = 10
4 + 3 / 1 * 2 = 10
4 * 1 + 2 * 3 = 10
4 * 1 + 3 * 2 = 10
4 * 1 * 3 - 2 = 10
4 * 2 + 3 - 1 = 10
4 * 2 - 1 + 3 = 10
4 * 3 * 1 - 2 = 10
4 * 3 - 1 * 2 = 10
4 * 3 - 2 * 1 = 10
4 * 3 - 2 / 1 = 10
4 * 3 / 1 - 2 = 10
4 / 1 + 2 * 3 = 10
4 / 1 + 3 * 2 = 10
4 / 1 * 3 - 2 = 10
```

Comment: Also, this gives the output RHS (`10`) of the same type as the `result` variable - aka integer in this case.